# Loadrunner - How do I simulate quitting or closing a browser-session in Web HTTP/HTML protocol?

Tags: loadrunner, stress-testing

I'm stress-testing an application that only allows users to exit the application in one of two ways:
 1. Quitting the open browser-session.
 2. Allowing 5 minutes of idle-time to elapse.

I'd like to be able to write syntax in the Loadrunner script that quits the browser session. The protocol I would like to use is Web HTTP/HTML.

Does anyone know how to do this, or have any advice?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think quitting and ending the session by closing the browser is possible. There has to be something else going on (e.g. sockets) otherwise the server has no way of knowing when the user closed the browser.

Comment: Have you placed a protocol analyzer on the conversation between your browser and server to see if anything is actually sent when someone closes a browser?

Answer (score 0):

record the close and see what you find is sent (or not sent) to the server